# Modals - How to specify custom template for modal

Tags: magento2, modal

How can I specify an custom template for an modal? I tried to specify the type and customTemplate, but no luck.
The template file is called modal-gallery.html and is placed on the same path as the modal-popup.

```
var modalOptions = {
    type: 'gallery',
    customTpl: 'gallery'
};
jQuery('<div />').modal(modalOptions).modal('openModal');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer by myself.
You need to define 'text!ui/template/modal/modal-gallery.html' as galleryTpl and use the modalOptions as below:

```
var modalOptions = {
type: 'gallery',
customTpl: 'gallery',
galleryTpl: galleryTpl,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, extending the answer provided above

1) Set your script

```
<script>
require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
        'text!ui/template/modal/modal-gallery.html'
    ],
    function($,modal, galleryTpl) {
        var options = {
            type: 'gallery',
            customTpl: 'gallery',
            galleryTpl: galleryTpl,
...
```

Where `type` and `customTpl` attributes, got the end of the custom name file

2) Place your new custom file on these path
frontend/`<brand>`/`<customTheme>`/Magento_Ui/web/templates/modal/modal-gallery.html

3) Tip, to prevent restyling all
- On your custom template, add to the first `<aside>` tag, the class `modal-popup`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please specify the same the path not for theme but for module? Where exactly should I place custom popup template?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for creating a template.

#### Theme

If you want to create a modal template in the theme, you should put the template file in the following path:

`<magento_root>/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Ui/web/templates/modal/exampleTemplate.html`

Now you can add your own template via requirejs just as it is originally in the ["Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal" code](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/4c36116dcf878e127059d9be9566a119783583f2/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/modal/modal.js#L13) and it will look like this `text!ui/template/modal/exampleTemplate.html`.

#### Module

For the module, it may be a path like this:

`<magento_root>/app/code/<Vendor>/<Module>/view/frontend/web/template/modal/exampleTemplate.html`

In this case the template path will start with the name of your module i.e. `<Vendor>_<Module>` (instead of Magento_UI module - that's where the prefix **ui** comes from). That path will look like this `text!<Vendor>_<Module>/template/modal/exampleTemplate.html`.

#### Usage of template

Now when you have a template created and you know what its path is, you can use it as a custom template of the modal. It may look like the code below:

```html
<div id="modal">
    <div class="modal-body-content">
        <h2>Modal Example</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
        'text!ui/template/modal/exampleTemplate.html' // for the template created in the theme
        // 'text!<Vendor>_<Module>/template/modal/exampleTemplate.html' // for the template created in the module
    ], function($, modal, exampleTpl) {

        const options = {
            type: 'custom',
            customTpl: exampleTpl,
            responsive: true,
            title: 'Custom modal template',
            buttons: []
        };

        modal(options, $('#modal')); // creates modal
        $('#modal').modal('openModal'); // opens modal
    });
</script>
```

- List of all options that can be set: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/javascript/jquery-widgets/modal/. There are also references and paths to the original Magento modal templates.